# htaccess - syntax to remove multiple query strings?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to remove certain URL parameters from my site, so Googlebot doesn't get confused & thinks it's duplicate content.

The parameters are:

- ?sort=
- ?limit=
- ?order=

Based on some examples I've come across, here's what I'm currently using in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "sort=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "limit=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "order=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

What is the proper syntax to combine these parameters into **one rule**?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good solution to remove the parameters if you need them.

The best way to avoid problems related to duplicate content, is to add in the html `<head>`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com/url-file.php?param=xxx">
```

By indicating the complete url of the page, with the only parameters you want to index by Google.

Comment: Google documentation: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternation in regex:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(limit|sort|order)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```